# NodeJs console.table in a forloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

so there is this NodeJS module called console.table where you can basically add tables inside the console. Here is an example from their website:

```
// call once somewhere in the beginning of the app
require('console.table');
console.table([
{
name: 'foo',
age: 10
}, {
name: 'bar',
age: 20
}
]);

// prints
name  age
----  ---
foo   10
bar   20
```

This is a mere example, I tried to automate it by putting it in a forloop, the forloop and code that I had hoped would work is this:

```
var values = [
]

for(var l = 0;l<config.accounts.username.length;l++) {
    values.push([

        {
            username: "Number "+l,
            itemtype: "Hello",
            amount: 10
        }, {
            itemtype: "Hello",
            amount: 10
        }

    ]);
}
console.table("", values);
```

Unfortunatly though, it does not work, can someone help me with this?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing an array of values into your array - remove the `[` & `]`

```
for(var l = 0;l<config.accounts.username.length;l++) {
    values.push(    
        {
            username: "Number "+l,
            itemtype: "Hello",
            amount: 10
        }, {
            itemtype: "Hello",
            amount: 10
        }

    );
}
```

Ref: [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

And then your original example didnt take 2 parameters it only took one so this

```
console.table("", values);
```

should possibly be

```
console.table(values);
```